# How to create ambience in inverted planet?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm creating a Game of Thrones world like (Intro), and it is an inverted planet. How can I create ambience (like Dynamic Sky) in this situation?

I've used mist pass and ambient occlusion... and is not what I'm asking about...

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks...

Edit 1: What I'm trying is to get rig of that flat looking. I do that in After Effects by adding Optical Flares, using 3d lights and tracking (or animating them manually) video. Using it carefully (low intensity) makes some "professional" looking to my shots... As a reference check the first 15 seconds of original GOT intro (1st season).

EDIT 2: I don't want to composite the "atmosphere". For that I can use even After Effects. I want it to be physical. Another thing I'd tried is to create volumetric clouds over the surface, but not what i'm looking for...

Any thoughts?

[image: GOT Intro 1]

[image: GOT Intro 2]

[image: GOT Intro 3]

[image]